# ASP.NET Core use Tag Helpers in Component View

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm developing a ASP.NET Core application (Visual Studio 2017 - Windows 10). The name of the project is SportWinkel. In my Views folder, there is a _ViewImports.cshtml file with this content:

```
@using SportWinkel

@addTagHelper SportWinkel.Infrastructure.*, SportWinkel
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCoreMvc.TagHelpers
```

I'm now adding a Component View in Views/Shared/Components/MyViewComponent (Default.cshtml), but tag helpers are not rendered by Razor.Only if I add this line on top of Default.cshtml, tag helpers are rendered correctly:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Very strange, because normally each view inside the Views folder imports _ViewImports.cshtml automatically...

Comment: I created a new project to test this, and I cannot reproduce. The tag helpers render correctly inside the viewcomponent

Comment: It could be a cache problem. Try to clean and rebuild. Also, try to switch the order of the tag helpers in the _viewimport

Answer (score 1):

Inside your _viewImports please put as its mentioned below there is slight mistake.

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```